# How to manually input nodes id to select/highlight nodes in visNetwork

Tags: r, neo4j, shiny, visnetwork

I am building a network using visNetwork package in Shiny app.

In visNetwork package, there is a **nodesIdSelection** argument in **visOption** function to select/highlight the nodes.

However, we can **only select nodes from the drop down menu**, **instead of manually input nodes id** to select in this function. It is hard to find node id if there is a lot of nodes ids in the drop down menu.

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this function. If it is not possible in visNetwork, I am thinking to implement possible functions in Shiny to solve it.

Below is my current code of visNetwork.

```
# data used in next examples
nb <- 10
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:nb, label = paste("Label", 1:nb),
                    group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], nb, replace = TRUE), value = 1:nb,
                    title = paste0("<p>", 1:nb,"<br>Tooltip !</p>"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

edges <- data.frame(from = c(8,2,7,6,1,8,9,4,6,2),
                    to = c(3,7,2,7,9,1,5,3,2,9),
                    value = rnorm(nb, 10), label = paste("Edge", 1:nb),
                    title = paste0("<p>", 1:nb,"<br>Edge Tooltip !</p>"))

visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "500px", width = "100%") %>% 
  visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, nodesIdSelection = TRUE) %>%
  visLayout(randomSeed = 123)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need a Shiny solution.

Comment: Thanks Ben, visNetwork has a function called visNetworkProxy that enables me to interact (select/focus) the network with Shiny. However, the select/focus function in visNetworkProxy is not 100% the same as it in visOptions. (eg. visOptions can show/highlight the only selected nodes and nodes connected to selected node, the select function in visNetworkProxy does not work this way). Do you have any thoughts on this? I appreciate it!

Comment: Benoit Thieurmel created this package with extreme generosity so us R users can use the javascript features without learning a new language (https://www.rdocumentation.org/collaborators/name/Benoit%20Thieurmel).  That being said, it doesn't allow full customization. Basically I think you can only get so far using this package and if you truly need full customization you have to go the full on javascript route.  I'd say 99 times out of 100 you don't really need that level of customization if your primary language is R.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'll go with visNetworkProxy interacting with Shiny.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shiny with `visSelectNodes` and set `highlightNearest` in options to achieved the same result. With this you can customize the input in shiny widget catalog as you preferred.

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)

server <- function(input, output) {
output$network_proxy_nodes <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
    
    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% 
        visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE)
})


observe({
        visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
            visSelectNodes(id = input$Focus, highlightEdges = T)
    })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 4,

            selectInput("Focus", "Focus on node :",
                    c(1:3))
        ),
        column(
            width = 8,
            visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_nodes", height = "400px")
        )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```